# How to change the layout if I change the orientation mode in Appcelerator

Tags: android, ios, xml, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I'm building an app with appcelerator studio. In my first activity I've a box with text, label, image and button.
The layout is good if the smartphone is in portrait mode, but if try to move the smartphone in landscape mode, the layout is not good.
Now there is a mode to create two graphic?

**For example:**

```
login.js
login-portrait.xml
login-landscape.xml
```

so from code, if the device is in landscape mode I load this xml layout, if the user change the orientation I load the other view.

It is possible to do this?

Comment: Add a postlayout event listener to your window and try to adjust the UI elements in the callback. http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-event-postlayout

Comment: thanks, your solution it is ok for now.